# No rendering target selected using Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

My Android Studio in activity_main.xml showing this problem: "Rendering Problems No render target selected"
Help?

Comment: close and reopen or api level make change For debug and Running...17 to 17 or 18 to 18,etc

Answer (score 7):

You need to run the AVD Manager to add a virtual device that matches the target API version your project is set to. Click Tools->Android->AVD Manager.  Click on 'New', add virtual devices targeting higher API levels, e.g 18, 19, etc. Then restart Android Studio, and open your project, it should find a target device to allow you access to the Design view.

Comment: You need atleast 1 AVD created for this badly designed tool. Seriously crap. thanks @Chinedu

Answer (score 5):

Top menu bar on the left side of the AVD Manager button you have a "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button. Click that. Android Studio may become sluggish for like 5 seconds, but you'll also see a loading wheel in the project files tab, and possibly a yellow bar on the top of activity_main.xml tab saying that Gradle is syncing. In about 5 seconds everything will be up to date, and you will see the device as expected. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it with `File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart`.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error and the reason was that in my application the targetSdkVersion was set to version I didn't have setup on my AndroidStudio, error disappeared after I modified that, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Android manifest file to see if you have specified this

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

If not then add this, it solved the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

You just make sure your right top corner api selection is below api 18 or 18 I think it will work
or you will goto graphics layout and see the top corner and change

Comment: Do you mean "Please configure an Android SDK. "? I changed it but there is nothing at right top corner!!

Comment: i am mentioning the api levels and will you able to post your screen shot

Comment: You just make sure you sdk path is configured correctly you just click the configure link and set the path of your sdk and then after setting your path just restart the android studio that's all

Answer (score 0):

Close the emulator if it is previously opened. Then try launching the fragment_main.xml again in design mode.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Android Studio and it should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Check the package name is correctly set in `applicationId` in file `app\build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Top menu bar on the left side of the AVD Manager button you have a "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button. Click that. Android Studio may become sluggish for like 5 seconds, but you'll also see a loading wheel in the project files tab, and possibly a yellow bar on the top of activity_main.xml tab saying that Gradle is syncing. In about 5 seconds everything will be up to date, and you will see the device as expected. Hope this helps.

This really works

If it says Gradle Sync failed then download the missing platforms and platforms and then restart

It worked for me..