# Android Studio Gradle and Rendering Issue

Tags: android, android-studio

This is the first time I am using Android Studio to create an android application.
When I load my "activity_main.xml" file for editing purpose it shows me the following error.

Please find below screenshots.

[image: Android Studio Rendering Error]

[image: Android Studio Gradle Error]

Please Suggest fixes if any.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems

Comment: just change the api that you trying to work with - this solve the problem mostly

Answer (score 0):

Try to click on Tools>Android>AVD Manager. Click New and select a device with a Target API higher than your Project API. After that restart Android Studio and load your Project. Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the AVD Manager to add a virtual device that matches the target API version your project is set to. Click Tools->Android->AVD Manager. Click on 'New', add virtual devices targeting higher API levels, e.g 18, 19, etc. Then restart Android Studio, and open your project, it should find a target device to allow you access to the Design view.

After this you sync your gradil this will solve your issue. For more [Check for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776653/no-rendering-target-selected-using-android-studio)